# PowerShell Custom Table and convert row to column

Tags: powershell

I have files in an array

```
$txt = @(P123456N123, P123456N122, P123456N223, P12asd6N122, P12asd6N124,
 P12asd6N201, P1235d6N124, P1235d6N123, P1235d6N122)
```

I need to get the last three digits of each file, already done.  What I'm struggling with is getting a table that looks like the below:

| File Name | Numbers |
| --- | --- |
| P123456N | 122, 123, 223 |
| P12asd6N | 122, 124, 201 |
| P1235d6N | 122, 123, 124 |

What I have so far is:

```
$table = @()
foreach ($file in $txt){
    $subNo = $file.basename.substring(($file.basename.length - 4),3)
    $FileName = $file.name.substring(0, 8)
    $table += [PSCustomObject] @{
    FileName = $FileName
    SubNo = $subNo
    }
}
```

I can then do `$table | Group-Object FileName` but that gives me a terribly formatted result and it isn't portable into a csv in the format listed below.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, which combines [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) and [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```sh
@(
 'P123456N123', 'P123456N122', 'P123456N223', 'P12asd6N122', 'P12asd6N124',
 'P12asd6N201', 'P1235d6N124', 'P1235d6N123', 'P1235d6N122'
) | 
  Group-Object { $_.Substring(0, 8) } | 
  Select-Object @{ Name='File Name'; Expression='Name'}, 
                @{ Name='Numbers'; Expression={ $_.Group.Substring(8) -join ', ' } }
```

To-display output:

```sh
File Name Numbers
--------- -------
P123456N  123, 122, 223
P1235d6N  124, 123, 122
P12asd6N  122, 124, 201
```

Comment: @topcity36, I've added the output I get to the answer, which seems to match what you're looking for (different ordering aside). Is this not what you see? Note that if you're working with `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances, you'll need to operate on their `.Name` or `.BaseName` properties, e.g. `$_.BaseName.Substring(0, 8)` and `$_.Group.BaseName.Substring(8)`

Comment: Yeah, looks good to me, I thought there was some duplication issues but it was caused by the input not the processing.  GiGo

Answer (score 1):

You could group the values using a *calculated expression* with [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2) and then iterate over the grouped objects to get the desired output:

```
$txt = @(
    'P123456N123', 'P123456N122', 'P123456N223', 'P12asd6N122', 'P12asd6N124',
    'P12asd6N201', 'P1235d6N124', 'P1235d6N123', 'P1235d6N122'
)

$txt | Group-Object { $_ -replace '\d{3}$' } | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'File Name' = $_.Name
        'Numbers'   = $_.Group -replace '.+(?=\d{3}$)' -join ', '
    }
}
```

The regex implies that all files **end with 3 numeric digits**.